# How to create a new file in github and add there existing files?

Tags: github

I have files in repository. I want them to be grouped inside a folder. How can I do this?

It seems that I need to add new file if I want to create a folder.

Answer (score 1):

From how you worded your question, it seems like you're trying to work on github directly from the website.
The usual way github works is:

- if you have a repo on github and you want to modify it, first 'clone' the repo into your local computer,

> use these instructions https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

- then just change folder structure like you would normally on File Explorer (windows) or Finder (mac),
- then follow the commit instructions and 'push' up your changes to github

> use these instructions

check status of your recent changes:
git status

add the files that you want to include in the commit 
git add nameOfFile

check status and the file you want to include should now be green 
git status

use this to send to github 
git push

Overall github docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/introduction-to-github/